Text jumps left when zooming UserForm in VBA
I have a user form and in order to get the form in full screen mode I have this lines on the initialize:
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

UserForm.Zoom=Int(Application.width/UserForm.width*100)

UserForm.StartUpPosition=0

UserForm.Left= Application.Left

UserForm.Top = Application.Top

UserForm.Width = Application.Width

UserForm.Height = Application.Width

The form enters full screens mode but all the button caption and multipage titles jumps to the left the alignment is all goes wrong.
Tried to play with the UserForm.zoom command line and it seems that the less the zoom is the less the text jumps left it is connected somehow but I can’t figure it out
Also tried to maximize the userform to the screens size.

I posted a new answer .Let me know if that is what you want?

If you want to zoom the Userform and the controls then you can try this. I am not changing the left and the top of the userform. Nor have I done any error handling. I am sure you can handle that. This is just a quick demo on how to zoom form and it's controls. I have also commented the code. Let me know if you still have questions.
I have created a separate reusable function to set the zoom. Enter the zoom value in the textbox and click the commandbutton.
I hope this is what you wanted?
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ZoomMyForm Me, TextBox1.Text
End Sub

'~~> This function will zoom a UserForm and its controls
Sub ZoomMyForm(MyFrm As Object, ZoomBy As Double)
    Dim origWidth As Single, origHeight As Single
    '~~> Store the original form dimensions
    origWidth = MyFrm.InsideWidth
    origHeight = MyFrm.InsideHeight
    
    '~~> Resize the form
    MyFrm.Width = MyFrm.Width * ZoomBy
    MyFrm.Height = MyFrm.Height * ZoomBy

    Dim origLeft As Single, origTop As Single
    Dim newWidth As Single, newHeight As Single
    Dim ctrl As Control
    
    '~~> Loop through each control on the form
    For Each ctrl In MyFrm.Controls
        '~~> Store the original ctrl dimensions and position
        origLeft = ctrl.Left
        origTop = ctrl.Top
        origWidth = ctrl.Width
        origHeight = ctrl.Height
        
        '~~> Resize and reposition the control based on the zoomby value
        ctrl.Left = origLeft * ZoomBy
        ctrl.Top = origTop * ZoomBy
        ctrl.Width = origWidth * ZoomBy
        ctrl.Height = origHeight * ZoomBy
        
        '~~> Adjust the font size for text-based controls
        On Error Resume Next
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.Label Or TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Or _
           TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CommandButton Or TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox Or _
           TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ListBox Then
            ctrl.Font.Size = ctrl.Font.Size * ZoomBy
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next ctrl
End Sub

In Action



